# Change ionic icon color by Angular

Tags: css, angularjs

I am trying to change ionic icon color. Like online (green), Idle (amber) and offline (Gray). So basically I am fetching the data by http request and it is working fine. It is showing the correct data but I am not able to show the online status.

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 trans">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4  trans"><i class="icon icon ion-person"></i> <font color="3E35EE"> {{fname}} {{lname}}</font></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4  trans"><i class="icon icon ion-location"></i> <font color="3E35EE"> {{city}}</font></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4  trans"><i class="icon icon ion-cash"></i><font color="3E35EE"> Salary</font></div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

This is the icon `<i class="icon icon ion-person"></i>` which color i want to change.

```
$scope.fname = data.fname;
                            $scope.lname = data.lname;
                            $scope.mobile = data.mobile;
                            $scope.last_seen = data.last_seen;
```

based upon the last_seen data i would like to change the color.
Data only comes at page load. Data is not refreshing all the time. So, only I need to change the color at once during page load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set a variable based on your $http callback and then apply the corresponding style with ng-style. See the documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) for ng-style.

```
<i class="icon icon ion-person" ng-style="myStyle"></i>
...

$scope.myStyle = {"color": "gray"};

$http({
    ...
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    ...
    $scope.myStyle = {"color": "green"};
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    ...
    $scope.myStyle = {"color": "red"};
});
```